# How do I get the hour part with SqlFunctions.DateName

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a query where I need to compare 24hour format Hour of a datetime property in an entity with a 24hour time string

example:

```
var time = "14:00";
var results = db.Table.Where(item => 
    SqlFunctions.DateName("HH:mm", item.DateTimeProperty) == time);
```

Although this throws the following

{"'HH:mm' is not a valid value for the DATEPART argument in the 'SqlServer.DATENAME' function."}

How can I convert a datetime property to 24hour-clock time with SqlFunctions?

Comment: Are you sure you need to compare the *formatted* time? Can you not just compare the time?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I didn't think of that. That way I'm avoiding all the conversions too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your use of SQL Server's DateName function is not quite right. Please try this:

```
var time = "14:00";
var hour = Int32.Parse(time.Substring(0, 2));
var minute = Int32.Parse(time.Substring(3, 2));
var results = db.Table.Where(item =>
    SqlFunctions.DateName("hh", item.DateTimeProperty) == hour &&
    SqlFunctions.DateName("n", item.DateTimeProperty) == minute);
```

Also see the [MSDN Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx).